# What is the difference between P(dx) and P(x)dx?

Tags: probability, statistics

I often come across the notation $P(dx)$ in statistics papers. Is there a strict mathematical definition for $dx$ inside $P$?

**Examples**:
What is the exact meaning of 
$$\int f(x)P(dx)$$
and 
$$\int f(x)P(x)dx$$
Also sometimes I saw $\frac{P(dx)}{Q(dx)}$, is it equivalent to $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}dx$?

Comment: where $P$ is a probaility measure? It just means the integral of $f$ with respect to the measure $P$ IIRC

Comment: I've not seen that -- but I have seen notation like $dF_X(x)$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: It's probably another notation for the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration . Please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 7):

If $P$ is a probability measure, then the notation $\int f(x) P(dx)$ is notation for the [measure-theoretic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration) of $f$ with respect to the probability measure $P$.
Another notation for $P(dx)$ that you might see is $dP(x)$.

Consider two concrete examples.

1. If $P$ is the distribution of a *continuous* random variable $X$ with density function $p_X$ ("distribution" means a probability measure on the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$), then
   $$
   \int f(x) \, P(dx) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) p_X(x) \, dx,
   $$
   where you can treat the right-hand side as an ordinary Riemann integral under many common scenarios.
2. If $P$ is the distribution of a *discrete* random variable $X$ taking values in a countable set $\mathcal{X} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with probability mass function $p_X$, then
   $$
   \int f(x) \, P(dx) = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f(x) p_X(x).
   $$

The benefit of the measure-theoretic approach is that you unify the theory of probability to get rid of the false dichotomy between continuous and discrete random variables: using measure theory, *every* expected value is an integral.

Answer (score -1):

Typical notation will use

$$ \int f(x) dP(x)  = \int f(x)P(x) dx $$

But the form you're using is also equivalent.

Comment: Can you provide a reference that uses this convention? I've never seen it.

Comment: See the section titled "Measurable functions" here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration

Comment: thanks, but I don’t see anything resembling $\int f(x) P(x) \, dx$ at that link

Comment: That was an example of $\int{f(x)dP(x)}$. The second equation is just the definition, and used in the question...

Comment: Sorry, I was asking for an example that uses the right-hand side to refer to the measure theoretic integral. I’ve never seen it used that way, and I don’t think it makes sense if $P$ is a probability measure